# How to change the context of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm trying to understand why in javascript, you might want to change the context of a function. I'm looking for a real world example or something which will help me understand how / why this technique is used and what its significance is.

The technique is illustrated using this example (from http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#25)

```
var object = {}; 
function fn(){ 
  return this; 
} 
assert( fn() == this, "The context is the global object." ); 
assert( fn.call(object) == object, "The context is changed to a specific object." );
```

Comment: Funny; I found this page because I need to set the context for a call I'm making and couldn't remember the syntax... :)

Comment: +1 should be titled: "How to change the context of a function in javascript" (jk - thanks for posting this!)

Comment: +1 I was looking for how to keep the this consistent within a class...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

jQuery makes use of it to good effect:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    // "this" is an a element - very useful
});
```

The actual jQuery code looks like this:

```
for ( name in object ) {
    if ( callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] ) === false ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

If it just did `callback( name, object[ name ] )` then `this` wouldn't be set to the current object in your iterator and you'd have to use the parameter instead.  Basically it just makes things easier.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first parameter to `.call()` becomes `this`. More details @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 6):

Please have a look at this example:

```
<script>
var el = document.getElementById('button');
el.onclick = function(){
    this.value = "Press Me Again"; //this --> now refers to the the element button not on the window
}

//Another Example:
var Person = function(name,location){
  this.name = name;
  this.location = location;  
  alert(this.location); 
}   
var p2 = new Person("Samantha","California"); //this refers to the instance of the function Person(Person now acts as a class)
var p1 = Person(); // this refers to the window(Person simply acts as a simple function)
</script>
<button id="button1">Press Me</button>
```

The new keyword changes the context.

Answer (score 3):

It's very useful when doing callbacks from AJAX requests:

```
function Person(_id, _name) {
    this.id = _id;
    this.name = _name;
};

Person.prototype.sayHi = function(greeting) {
    alert(greeting + " from " + this.name);
};

Person.prototype.loadFromAJAX = function(callback) {
    // in this example, it's jQuery, but could be anything
    var t = this;
    $.get("myurl.php", function(data) {
        callback.call(t, data.greeting);
    });
};
```

Actually, that's a pretty crappy example.

There are tons of uses of it in jQuery. For example, the jQuery().get() function:

```
get: function( num ) {
    return num === undefined ?
        // Return a 'clean' array
        Array.prototype.slice.call( this ) :
        // Return just the object
        this[ num ];
}
```

It's using the functions of the Array prototype but in the context of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

A real world example that i've encountered:

If you add a function as an event handler to a DOM element and if you use "this" inside that function, "this" will refer to the DOM element that you added the event handler to.

But that function might be a method of an object and you want the "this" keyword used inside it to refer to the owner object...so you need to change the context so that "*this*" will not refer to the **DOM element** but will refer to the **owner object**.

You can easily change the context of a function in jquery using the proxy() function.
See this question:
[jquery "this" binding issue on event handler (equivalent of bindAsEventListener in prototype)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864378/jquery-this-binding-issue-on-event-handler-equivalent-of-bindaseventlistener)
and the first answer

Answer (score 1):

bind function  might be what you're looking for, bind function returns a new function with in the context that you passed in , a real world scenario could be when you are using jquery delegates to attach some behavior to a dom element, and you want the callback being execute in a different context.  'cause the default context in a jquery delgate is the dom object that is bound to the handler , which means you can't access any property besides the properties that belongs to the dom object

Answer (score 0):

I always find myself in the need of having different context when using `setTimeout` and jQuery has a handy function [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) which does the trick:

```
function iAmCalledAfterTimeout()
{
     alert(this.myProperty); //it will alert "hello world"
}    

setTimeout($.proxy(iAmCalledAfterTimeout, {myProperty:"hello world"}), 1000);
```