# addEventListener and `this` not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom-events

I am an experienced programmer, but somewhat new to web programming.  I am trying to learn Javascript, HTML5 and SVG using VS2010 by writing an HTML page that plays Tic-Tac-Toe with Javascript.

I am successfully creating each of the nine squares as SVG `<rect...>` elements, however I am having trouble with the click event handlers for each square.

Here's the base SVG elements as they exist in the HTML file:

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
    id="svgTTT" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 300 300"  >
    <rect width="3" height="300" x="99" fill="#008d46" />
    <rect width="3" height="300" x="199" fill="#000000" />
    <rect width="300" height="3" y="99" fill="#008d46" />
    <rect width="300" height="3" y="199" fill="#d2232c" />
  </svg>
```

These static `<rect>` elements draw the for cross-hash lines of the TicTacToe board.  The nine board squares are created in a javascript function called from the windows load event (below).

Here's the javascript (in-line in a `<script>` element in the HTML body):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getEl(s) { return document.getElementById(s); }

  var svg;  // get the TTT svg

  // execute after HTML has rendered
  window.onload = function () {
    svg = getEl("svgTTT");
    tttSetupSquares(svg);
    alert("click-squares are setup.");
  }

  var cells = new Array(3);
  // setup the click squares
  function tttSetupSquares(brd) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      cells[i] = new Array(3);
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var x = 3 + (i * 100);
        var y = 3 + (j * 100);
        var newId = "svgTTTsqr" + i.toString() + j.toString();
        // add in new rect with html
        brd.innerHTML += "<rect id='"+newId+"' width='93' height='93' "
                        + "fill='#00DD00' x='" + x.toString() + "' y ='" + y.toString() + "'"
                        + " />";
        //find it using the newId
        var rect = document.getElementById(newId);
        //make a cell object to contain all of this
        var cell = {
          col: i,
          row: j,
          pSvg: svg,
          rect: rect,

          handleClick: function (event) {
            try {
              // this line fails because `this` is the target, not the cell
              var svgNS = this.pSvg.namespaceURI;

              var line = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'line');
              this.pSvg.appendChild(line);
            }
            catch (err) {
              alert("handlClick err: " + err);
            }
          }
        }

        //add a click handler for the rect/cell
        cell.rect.addEventListener("click", cell.handleClick, false);
        //(only seems to work the last time it is executed)

        //save the cell object for later use
        cells[i][j] = cell;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

(I can supply the full page source, but it's just the HTML elements that contain these.)

The problem is two-fold:

1. Only the last `addEventListener` seems to work. Clicking on all of the other squares does nothing. Clicking on the last square (svgTTTsqr22) does run the `cell.handleClick` but leads to problem 2 (below).  Chrome Developer Tools (F12) shows all of the `<rect>` elements except the last as having no event listener.
2. When the `cell.handleClick` does run, it fails on the fist line (`var svgNS = this.pSvg.namespaceURI;`) with an error like "*undefined object does not have a property named "namespaceURI*"  Inspection in Devleoper Tools shows that it is failing because `this` is not set to the `cell` object but rather to the SVG `<rect>` element that was clicked.

So my questions are:

A. What am I doing wrong here, and

B. How can/should I be doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Missing event handlers**

Using `innerHTML` to alter an element's internal structure will cause all of its children to be removed and the element's DOM sub-tree to be rebuilt by re-parsing the HTML content. By removing the child elements all previously registered event listener will get lost and will not automatically be restored when rebuilding the DOM from HTML. To circumvent this behaviour it's good practice to avoid `innerHTML`, if possible, and use direct DOM manipulation instead. You could use something like this to insert your `<rect>`s:

```
// Use DOM manipulation instead of innerHTML
var rect = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'rect');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", newId);
rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "#00DD00");
rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "93");
rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "93");
rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
svg.appendChild(rect);
```

**2. `this` context inside of event handlers**

Whenever an event listener gets called `this` will get bound to the element where the event got triggered by. In your code, however, you won't need `this` because all information is available by the parameter `brd` which gets passed in to function `.tttSetupSquares()`.

```
handleClick: function (event) {
    try {
        var svgNS = brd.namespaceURI;
        var line = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'line');
        brd.appendChild(line);
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("handlClick err: " + err);
    }
}
```

See the following snippet for a working example:

```js
function getEl(s) { return document.getElementById(s); }

  var svg;  // get the TTT svg
  var cells = new Array(3);

  // execute after HTML has rendered
  !(function () {
    svg = getEl("svgTTT");
    tttSetupSquares(svg);
    alert("click-squares are setup.");
  }());

  // setup the click squares
  function tttSetupSquares(brd) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      cells[i] = new Array(3);
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var x = 3 + (i * 100);
        var y = 3 + (j * 100);
        var newId = "svgTTTsqr" + i.toString() + j.toString();
        
        // Use DOM manipulation instead of innerHTML
  var rect = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'rect');
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", newId);
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "#00DD00");
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "93");
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "93");
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
        svg.appendChild(rect);
        
        //make a cell object to contain all of this
        var cell = {
          col: i,
          row: j,
          pSvg: brd,
          rect: rect,

          handleClick: function (event) {
            try {
              //console.log(this);
              var svgNS = brd.namespaceURI;
              var line = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'line');
              line.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", this.x.baseVal.value);
              line.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", this.y.baseVal.value);
              line.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", this.x.baseVal.value + this.width.baseVal.value);
              line.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", this.y.baseVal.value + this.height.baseVal.value);
              brd.appendChild(line);
            }
            catch (err) {
              alert("handlClick err: " + err);
            }
          }
        }

        //add a click handler for the rect/cell
        cell.rect.addEventListener("click", cell.handleClick, false);

        //save the cell object for later use
        cells[i][j] = cell;
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
line {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
    id="svgTTT" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 300 300"  >
    <rect width="3" height="300" x="99" fill="#008d46" />
    <rect width="3" height="300" x="199" fill="#000000" />
    <rect width="300" height="3" y="99" fill="#008d46" />
    <rect width="300" height="3" y="199" fill="#d2232c" />
  </svg>
```

Comment: Hmm, I had been wondering what the downsides to `innerHtml` must be.  I will try this...

Comment: Why is this the answer? The purpose of the rect is not to draw a line, but to be clickable and having the right context for this in the handler. How is this answer solving the problem? The snippet doesn't even work

Comment: @HolgerWill I only just saw you comment.  I marked this post as the answer because it correctly identified both things that I was doing wrong.  First that I was using a loop that set .InnerHtml, then added the Rect event, thus the InnerHtml mods were causing all of the prior Rect events to be lost.  Second that `this` was not working at all as I had thought in the event-handler.  Your answer was very detailed on the `this` issue (so I did upvote it) but missed the InnerHtml problem, so I choose this post as the answer.  As for the snippet not working, I didn't try it but just fixed my own code

Comment: @RBarryYoung To wrap this up I completed my snippet to not only fix the errors but to also be visually appealing ;-)

Comment: @altocumulus, the context of `this` in your event handler ist still the rect not the abstract cell object. If you want to go with that approach, all additional data you need has to be stored on the rect itself ( for example if it where clicked, or its index inside the board etc) this can be  done quite easily. the recommeded way of doing this is data-* attributes. so at least store the index of the cells data-attributes...
`cell.rect.setAttribute("data-col",i)` and `cell.rect.setAttribute("data-row",j)` so later in your click handler you can do `this.getAttribute("data-index-i")`

Comment: In the end you still end up having all data in two data structure first on your object and second on your rects... best to get the context right in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As explained above, the problem with "this" is that it gets bound to a context, which is not always the context you want. There are many solution for this type of problem. From the infamous `self=this` trick to `.bind()`. There are also many many answers to this, and in general it might by a duplicate. A good answer and some followup reading can be found here:
[var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this)
or here: [How to change the context of a function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536164/how-to-change-the-context-of-a-function-in-javascript)
or here: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/
or here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Though **the real answer to your question is very specific**. In the case of event handlers, there is a solution to the "this"-problem. You just have to implement an EventListener interface. This sounds more complicated than it is. In fact its quite easy. Your object just has to implement one function: `.handleEvent`. When you pass an object to an addEventListener() function, it is this function that gets called automatically. The nice thing about this is, that using this method, the context of "this" will automatically be right. No need for hacks or workarounds. It sure is good to know the workarounds for the general case, but **for this specific case, `.handleEvent` is the solution**.

here is a complete working example:

```js
  function getEl(s) { return document.getElementById(s); }

  var svg;  // get the TTT svg

  // execute after HTML has rendered
  window.onload = function () {
    svg = getEl("svgTTT");
    tttSetupSquares(svg);
    //alert("click-squares are setup.");
  }

  var cells = new Array(3);
  // setup the click squares
  function tttSetupSquares(brd) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      cells[i] = new Array(3);
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var x = 3 + (i * 100);
        var y = 3 + (j * 100);
        var rect= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","rect")
rect.setAttribute("x",x);
rect.setAttribute("y",y);
rect.setAttribute("width",100);
rect.setAttribute("height",100);
rect.setAttribute("fill","grey")

        brd.appendChild(rect)
        var cell = {
          col: i,
          row: j,
          pSvg: svg,
          rect: rect,

          handleEvent: function (event) {
            try {
              // this line fails because `this` is the target, not the cell
              var svgNS = this.pSvg.namespaceURI;

              var line = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'line');
              line.setAttribute("x1",this.rect.getAttribute("x"))
              line.setAttribute("y1",this.rect.getAttribute("y"))
              line.setAttribute("x2",this.rect.getAttribute("x")*1+this.rect.getAttribute("width")*1)
              line.setAttribute("y2",this.rect.getAttribute("y")*1+this.rect.getAttribute("height")*1)
              line.setAttribute("stroke","red")
              this.pSvg.appendChild(line);
              document.getElementById("out").innerHTML="rect("+this.col+","+this.row+") was clicked"
            }
            catch (err) {
              alert("handlClick err: " + err);
            }
          }
        }

        //add a click handler for the rect/cell
        cell.rect.addEventListener("click", cell, false);
        //(only seems to work the last time it is executed)

        //save the cell object for later use
        cells[i][j] = cell;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
    id="svgTTT" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 300 300"  >
    <rect width="3" height="300" x="99" fill="#008d46" />
    <rect width="3" height="300" x="199" fill="#000000" />
    <rect width="300" height="3" y="99" fill="#008d46" />
    <rect width="300" height="3" y="199" fill="#d2232c" />
  </svg>

<div id="out"></div>
```

in the case of EventHandlers, this is the correct solution, everything else is a hack!

Comment: May I ask the downvoters what's wrong with my answer? I will be pleased to correct it so it becomes a better answer.

Comment: NOTE: this answer was also very helpful in resolving my problem. +1

Answer (score 2):

Some advice:

You could look into using event delegation. If you use a framework or library like jQuery or Angular or React, it will do event delegation for you automatically. Having many event handlers on separate DOM elements can hurt performance. What you could do instead is to have a "click" handler on the wrapping element, and use the `event.target` property to see which element that was actually clicked.

```
svg.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === "rect" && (/^svgTTTsqr/).test(e.target.id)) {
        // Use a regexp on  e.target.id to find your
        // cell object in `cells`
    }
});
```

A regexp might be a little dirty so perhaps you should use data attributes instead.

```
// Generating the HTML
brd.innerHTML += "<rect id='"+newId+"' data-i='" + i + "' data-j='" + j + "' "

// The event handler:
svg.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === "rect" && (/^svgTTTsqr/).test(e.target.id)) {
        var i = e.target.getAttribute("data-i");
        var j = e.target.getAttribute("data-j");
        var cell = cells[i][j];
        cell.handleClick();
    }
});
```

If you do this you can also easily do another performance tweak which is to generate the entire HTML string first, and append it to the DOM in a single operation, since you no longer have to insert the HTML into the DOM and add the event listener while looping.

As for your questions,

1) Sorry, can't help you there :( Would need to set up an executable example and poke around, can't think of anything when reading the code. I'm going to post this answeranyway as hopefully the event delegation solution explained above would make the problem go away.

2) Raw functions called plainly have their 'this' bound to whatever scope they are called in. The caller can also explicitly set what 'this' is bound to. The solution is to create a new function that is wrapped so that 'this' is forced to be whatever you want it to be. Use the built-in `function () {}.bind(cell)` which will return a new function that wraps the original and in the original `this` will always be set to `cell` regardless of the context the function returned by `bind` is called in.